# How to deploy a Ruby on Rails app to AWS-EC2 Ubuntu Linux using Apache 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We want to configure Apache to work with a Rails app. We want Apache to do load control. We cannot get them to work together. We are using MySQL for the database.  If we could please have some type of instruction or tutorial to follow to be able to deploy our application in AWS-EC2, it will be greatly appreciated.

We have a domain and we want to have multiple Rails app running in the same domain. Each rails app seems to want to run in a different port. We do not want to expose port 80/443. Apache is managing the inbound request. My attempts to use the host file has not been successful.

Comment: "Load Control" means what exactly you want to achieve can you elaborate?

Comment: We have a domain and we want to have multiple Rails app running in the same domain. Each rails app seems to want to run in a different port. We do not want to expose port 80/443. Apache is managing the inbound request. My attempts to use the host file has not been successful.

Comment: Read about `proxypass`